# Python assignment and test of function using elif

Tags: python, if-statement, variable-assignment

I have seen questions similar to this but not quite the same. I have an expression

```
if foo == ....
  return -1
elif myFunction(bar) != -1:
  return myFunction(bar)
elif ...
```

I don't want to calculate `myFunction(bar)` twice. If it were simply an `if`, I could do

```
temp = myFunction(bar)
if temp != -1
  return temp
```

However doing this with an `elif` would result in unnecessary calculations of `temp` if we were to follow the intitial `if`.

I can see a solution using an

```
if ...
else
  temp = myFunction(bar)
  if temp != -1:
    return temp
  elif ...
```

But that now starts to become more ugly. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you do not want to call `myFunction(bar)` twice and if you only can/want to call it after checking your `foo`, then there is no other way than using an intermediate variable to store the result in. There is no magic to get around this basic logical problem :-). I think a solution is not ugly when it reflects the right logic. You just have to be careful where to place the last `elif`.

Comment: But the `if` (at least in the example) contains a `return` anyway, so you *could* just use a temporary value and start a new `if` block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do this a lot, it might pay to have a [memoizing decorator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize) around. The only memoizer that is currently in the standard library (for newer Python 3.x) is `lru_cache`, which is overkill, but shows the general idea:

```
>>> def func():
...     print("foo")
...     return 1
... 
>>> if func():
...     print(func())
...     
foo
foo
1
```

Now memoize `func`:

```
>>> from functools import lru_cache
>>> func = lru_cache(1)(func)
>>> if func():
...    print(func())
...     
foo
1
```

Comment: "If you do this a lot" is the key point here. Otherwise the whole approach is just OTT.

Answer (score 7):

If you do not want to call myFunction(bar) twice then there is no other way than using an intermediate variable to store the result in. People here start proposing complex caching solutions for this. This can be pretty convenient in extreme cases, but before doing so, let's get back to the basics a bit. You should make proper use of the fact that you want to return from within your conditional blocks. In these situations you can save many `else`s. What follows now basically is the code block from your question, but without dots, with proper indentation, and with names according to PEP8:

```
if foo == "bar"
    return -1
elif myfunction(bar) != -1:
    return myfunction(bar)
else
    return None
```

It can easily be replaced with:

```
if foo == "bar"
    return -1
t = myfunction(bar)
if t != -1:
    return t
return None
```

As already stated in another answer, you can call your function twice if it does not affect the performance of your code. The result would look as simple as

```
if foo == "bar"
    return -1
if myfunction(bar) != -1:
    return myfunction(bar)
return None
```

Answer (score 1):

If your function call is simple enough, you could go with calling twice. Python doesn't have support for assign and compare feature. So, you have to trade off readability/elegance with performance.

Answer (score 0):

you could also make a function [promise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) like this:

```
class Promise():
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.__func = func;
        self.__computed = False;

    def Get(self):
        if not self.__computed:
            self.__result = self.__func()
            self.__computed = True
        return self.__result

def func(text):
    print text
    return 1

    f = Promise(lambda: func("compute"))
    >>> f.Get()     # first call, compute
    compute
    1
    >>> f.Get()     # second call, return result
    1
```